# Javascript & Html - current month list not showing current and also shows wrong dates in UTC

Tags: javascript, list, date

I got html + java on working web page however something in the script is not correct and I really can not find what to change, also I don't want to use other scripts in order to avoid page errors but to adjust current one.

In main.js with over 500 lines there is code for date and time which take list from json and they are based on UTC but everyone who is in O+ time zone gets correct date and if there is someone in 0- timezone then it shows day early...

Example of line in json

```
"2020-08-10T11:30:00.000Z",
```

In the code I have only one line related to timezone

```
jQuery('.timezone').text(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone)
```

I did try to change but didnt help.

Also there is drop down list with months to select and get dates of events but if Im in current month and I dont have event then it doesn't shows any date for next month.
Example: if I dont have anything in json for August then September doesn't show until 1.september when it become current month.

I found manual workaround for month to show

```
var now = new Date()
var currentYear = now.getFullYear()
var currentMonth = now.getMonth() + 1
var currentMonthDisplay = currentMonth.toString().length > 1 ? currentMonth : '0' + currentMonth
var selectedMonth = currentYear + '-' +  currentMonthDisplay
```

I change +1 to +2 to show next month as current but drop down list showing wrong month.

Related to drop down month there is

```
    monthSelector.on('change', function (e) {
    selectedMonth = e.target.value
    createList();
})
```

Extracted lines (over 100) that are related to dates I pasted in file attached https://gofile.io/d/P8RElW in order to prevent big question text.

I would appreciate at least directions I should look or something that is obvious to you that has to be changed.

Comment: Do you understand http://javascriptisnotjava.com/ ? Your title does not match your tags.

Comment: "2020-08-10T11:30:00.000Z" is UTC, however because the time is set to 11:30 and the largest -ve offset is -10, everyone with a -ve offset should see the same date, 2020-08-10. The maximum +ve offset is +14, so users in Kiribati will see the following day's date (at 01:30:00). However, the question doesn't say what your actual problem is. Do you want everyone to see the same date, or are you confused by the change from UTC to local? If you just want the date, then `"2020-08-10T11:30:00.000Z".substring(0,10)` will do.

Comment: Thank you all for answers.
Problem is that everyone who are in current date should get that date listed and not date from yesterday.
For example today is August 4th but people in US see it as August 3rd even their laptop clock shows August 4th.
Let me try this with substring you wrote.